# Crystal Report crosstab - total as percentage

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report with a cross tab table as below:

```
            10:00    11:00    12:00    13:00   Total
Person A        1        5       10        2      18
Person B        3       11       16        5      35
Person C        0        5        6        1      12
Total           4       21       32        8      65
```

I am trying to add another total that displays as a percentage as so:

```
            10:00    11:00    12:00    13:00   Total  % of Tot
Person A        1        5       10        2      18       28%
Person B        3       11       16        5      35       54%
Person C        0        5        6        1      12       18%
Total           4       21       32        8      65
% of Tot       6%      32%      49%      12%
```

I have tried a few methods so far, all of which have failed.

I've used a calculated member, this can only be displayed before the total and has to be formatted the same as the values so can't be a percentage.

I've tried adding two summary fields, one count and one percentage, then suppressing the percentage in the values and suppressing the value in the total, this however leaves lots of empty spaces and also doesn't show a figure total.

I've also considered abandoning a cross tab and doing everything within the report but in reality I have up to 20 columns (30 minute intervals) and the thought of 20 formulas for every value is pretty daunting.

Is there any way I can get around this limitation in Crystal Reports?

Comment: you should be able to get using calculated member...what is the problem can you elaborate?

Comment: @Siva I can't get the calculated member to appear after the total, I can get it to appear before on the last data row but then it shares the data formatting and can't display as a percentage.